# Python 2.7 with BeautifulSoup Error: Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do some webcrawling in a site with BeautifulSoup. But I'm getting an error when I'm trying to get the content inside the div class AddressInfo, Here is a piece of the site that I want to crawl:

```
<h4>Altônia</h4>
<div class="addressInfo">
Rua Getulio Vargas, 1201<br>
Centro - Iporã - PR<br>
87550-000<br>
<br>
(44) 3659-2721<br>
<a href="mailto:altoniacentro.pr@escolas.com.br">altoniacentro.pr@escolas.com.br</a><br>
</div>
```

And this is my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Copy all of the content from the provided web page
webpage = urlopen('site url....').read()


# Grab everything that lies between the h4 tags using a REGEX
patFinderTitle = re.compile('<h4>(.*)</h4>')

# Grab everything that lies between the class addressInfo tags using a REGEX
patFinderAddress = re.compile('<div class="addressInfo">(.*)</div>') **<- get error here**
```

And this is the error I get:

> ```
> raise ValueError('Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern') ValueError: Cannot process flags argument with a compiled
> ```
>
> pattern

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you use regex when you can just use BeautifulSoup for parsing? Besides, please paste all of your code. The code you pasted looks incomplete and produces no errors in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use xpath, it's easyer:
Try this:

```
 from lxml import html
    import requests

    url = 'http://.....'

    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    a = tree.xpath('//h4/text()')
    b = tree.xpath('//div[@class="addressInfo"]/text()')
    c = tree.xpath('//a//text()')

    print  a, b, c
```